# A continuous mapping is determined by its values on a dense set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let f and g be continuous mappings of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$ and let $E$ be a dense subset of $X$. Prove that $f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$. If $g(p)=f(p)$ for all $p \in E$, prove that $g(p)=f(p)$ for all $p \in X$.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: The second part is done [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458094/continuous-mapping-is-determined-by-its-values-on-a-dense-subset-of-its-domain?rq=1). I’m pretty sure that the first part has also been done here.

Comment: for the first one we have to prove $\bar{f(E)}$ $\subset$ f(X).
I have done the part f(X) $\subset$ $\bar{f(E)}$. Having problem with the reverse..

Comment: For the first part you need only show that if $U$ is a non-empty open subset of $Y$, then $U\cap f[E]\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: Why it is so? @ Brian M. Scott

Comment: To show that $f(X)\subset \overline{f(E)}$ is sufficient for the first part. Note that “$f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$” means that the closure of $f(E)$ *in* $f(X)$ is $f(X)$.

Comment: Why not the reverse part? @Carsten Schultz

Comment: Make sure that for $A\subset B\subset Y$ you understand what “$A$ is dense in $B$” means. If $B$ is not closed in $Y$ then it does *not* mean that $\overline A=B$.

Comment: I am not geting what you r saying. Please discuss it in detail. @ Carsten Schultz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a beautiful problem. Are you doing it in Rudin? Please note that I'm using a very particular definition of density. $E$ being dense in $X$ implies that, for any $x \in X$, we have that for all $\epsilon > 0$ we can find some $p\in E$ so that $d(p,x) < \epsilon$.

So we know $f$ is continuous and $E$ is dense... we should expect to use both of these definitions. Let's prove the first question.

Fix $y\in f(X)$. We want to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find some $w\in f(E)$ so that $d(y,w) < \epsilon$. This guarantees that $f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$. We know that $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in X$. Moreover, we know that for any $\epsilon$, we can find a $\delta$ so that $$d(x,p) < \delta \Rightarrow d(f(x), f(p)) < \epsilon.$$ For this particular choice of $\delta$, we can find $p\in E$ so that $d(x,p) < \delta$, since $E$ is dense in $X$. Then $f(p) \in f(E)$ and also we have demonstrated that $d(y, f(p)) < \epsilon$, so choosing $w=f(p)$ we have shown exactly what we set out to prove.

Now onto the second question. We are given that $f(p) = g(p)$ for every $p\in E$. Fix some $x \in X$. We'll show that for any such $x$ we'll have $f(x) = g(x)$.

Since $E$ is dense in $X$, for any $n \in N$, we can choose some $p_n \in E$ so that $d(x,p_n) < \frac{1}{n}$. Thus $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} p_n = x$. So we have that $$f(x) = f(\lim p_n) = \lim f(p_n) = \lim g(p_n) = g(\lim p_n) = g(x)$$ where we able to 'commute' the limit with the function each time because $f$ and $g$ are continuous. Also, we were able to replace $f$ with $g$ because they are equal for every $p_n \in E$.

Comment: Ya. I'm going through Rudin and found this one. Very nice solution u hv given.

Answer (score 4):

For the first part it is not restrictive to assume $f$ is surjective.

Suppose $U$ is an open set in $Y=f(X)$ such that $U\cap f(E)=\emptyset$. Then $f^{-1}(U)\cap E=\emptyset$ and therefore, by density, $f^{-1}(U)=\emptyset$, so also $U=\emptyset$. Thus every nonempty open set of $f(X)$ has nonempty intersection with $f(E)$, which is density.

For the second part, note that $W=\{x\in X:f(x)\ne g(x)\}$ is open in $X$. Indeed, if $x\in W$, take disjoint neighborhoods $U_1$ and $U_2$ of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, respectively. Then $V=f^{-1}(U_1)\cap g^{-1}(U_2)$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and $V\subseteq W$. Hence $W$ is open.

As a consequence $E\subseteq X\setminus W$; since $X\setminus W$ is closed and $X$ is the only closed subset of $X$ containing $E$ (by density), we are done.

---

Notes. The first part is true for any continuous map between topological spaces. The second part is true for any continuous map between topological spaces, provided the codomain is Hausdorff.